# How do I pass a variable into this partial to use as a counter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<div class="postSlideshowDots">
                <%for i in @post.images%>
                 <%=render :partial => "dots", :locals => {:image => i }%>     
                <%end%>
</div>
```

I would like to also pass in a variable (=0 when it goes in) to use as a counter. I had read that there was one already built in, "partialname_counter", but that gave me an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `<%= render :partial => "dots", :collection => @post.images %>`, and you will get a variable called `dots_counter` in the partial. You will also need to change your partial to use `dots` instead of `image` as the variable.

Finally, don't use `for..in` in Ruby, it is non-idiomatic, and has some bad behavior in regards to closures and scoping. Use `.each`

Comment: Plus, `for` calls `each` anyway, so it’s unnecessary indirection.

Comment: You can use `render partial: 'dots', collection: @post.images, as: 'image'` if you dont want to change the variable name in the partial